# Every element of the field extension $k(\alpha)$ can be written as a rational function in $\alpha$ with coefficients in $k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $k \subset F$ be a field extension, and let $\alpha \in F$. Prove that the field $k(\alpha)$ consists of all the elements of $F$ which may be written as rational functions in $\alpha$, with coefficients in $k$.

I think that if $\alpha$ is transcendental, then $k(\alpha) \cong k(t)$ via $\alpha \leftrightarrow t$.

If $\alpha$ is algebraic, and $p(x)$ is it minimal polynomial, then $k(\alpha) \cong k[x]/(p(x))$. However, I don't see how to write elements of $k(\alpha)$ as rational functions in $\alpha$.

The isomorphism $k(\alpha) \cong k[x]/(p(x))$ comes from $k[x] \to k(\alpha)$ sending $x \mapsto \alpha$. This factors through $k[x]/p(x)$ giving the isomorphism.

So, it seems every element of $k(\alpha)$ can be written as $f(\alpha)$, which is technically a rational function in $\alpha$.

However, I believe the point of the exercise is to show that an element of $k(\alpha)$ is $f(\alpha)/g(\alpha)$.

Is there more to this exercise?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is algebraic, then every element is the image of some $p(x)\in k[x]$ via $p(x)\mapsto p(\alpha)$. Luckily, polynomials are rational functions, by taking the denominator to be the constant polynomial $1$.

Comment: "So, it seems every element of $k(\alpha)$ can be written as $f(\alpha)$, *which is technically a rational function in* $\alpha$." What is there more to say? Certainly for algebraic extensions you can't expect a surjective evaluation $k(x)\to k(\alpha)$ of $x$ because of the zero denominators.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Can there exists any other surjective homomorphisms $k(x) \to k(\alpha)$?

Comment: @user46372819 homomorphisms of fields must be injective, so no, there is none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: don't worry about whether $\alpha$ is algebraic over $k$. $k(\alpha)$ is the intersection of all subfields of $F$ that contain $k$ and $\alpha$. Now prove (1) that any subfield of $F$ that contains $k$ and $\alpha$ also contains any (well-defined) rational function $f(\alpha)/g(\alpha)$ with all coefficients in $k$ and (2) that the set of all such well-defined rational functions of $\alpha$ is a subfield of $F$. ("Well-defined" here just means that $g(\alpha) \neq 0$.)

Comment: Any subfield of $F$ that contains $k$ and $\alpha$ contains $k(\alpha)$. If $g(\alpha) \ne 0$, then $f(\alpha)/g(\alpha) \in k(\alpha)$. So, any subfield of $F$ containing $k$ and $\alpha$ contains the set of all well-defined $f(\alpha)/g(\alpha)$. If $f_1(\alpha)/g_1(\alpha)$ and $f_2(\alpha)/g_2(\alpha)$ are well-defined, then we can add/multiply them hence, $\{f(\alpha)/g(\alpha) \mid g(\alpha) \ne 0\}$ is a field. Since this field containing $k$ and $\alpha$, and contained in $k(\alpha)$, then it must be $k(\alpha)$.

Comment: Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Reminder: you also need to show that inverses exist in part 2.